# How to keep a large array in memory for fast reuse in native Python code?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm using Python 3.6 to load a large array from disk, and then perform some task on the array. Basically, the script looks like this:

```py
import pickle

def some_task(arr):
    # arr is read-only through the task
    # for example:
    result = arr.sum()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = pickle.load(open(FILE_PATH_TO_PICKLED_ARRAY, "rb"))
    some_task(arr)
```

Since I'm still working on the code, I often have to change the implementation of `some_task` and run the script to see the result. However, it takes quite a while to load the large array from disk into memory. As a result, every time I try to test even a small change, I have to wait minutes for the exact same array to be reloaded. I think this is an unnecessary repetition.

My question is: is there some Python-native way to keep the array in memory (unless I manually release it or kill the process), so that the array can be readily reused in such cases?

My thoughts on this: I expect to have a "server" process that loads the large array into memory once and for all, and then shares it with another "client" (sub)process. The "child" (sub)process should somehow be able to access the "server" process's memory space with low overhead (which I guess is hard as the OS prevents it? BTW my environment is Linux 5.4.0), and it should support re-launch of the "client" after a change on the code, something like hot plugging. The inter-process communication should not involve object pickling, otherwise it is meaningless. I wonder if the shared array with `multiprocessing` (e.g., [this blog](https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2018/03/on-sharing-large-arrays-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing.html)) could provide a solution.

I know a database could do this, but in my case, a database seems like an overkill. I also do not want to bother my supervisor to set up any addtional softwares on the server. I would prefer a Python-only workaround. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you ever tried [`memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)? It can help you avoid unnecessary loading of the entire array.

Comment: The complicated architecture you describe is basically ipython, or more recently jupyter notebooks. Is there any reason you can't use one of these? I use them to load up my data and analyze it with new functions on the fly all day long.

Comment: @RichardSheridan Hi! I wasn’t aware of ipython or Jupyter before, and thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I think they can solve the problem. However, I feel that switching to a different framework/tool might be overkill. I usually code with native Python using vim on a remote lab server (no GUI) via ssh. I’m concerned about the learning curve of Jupyter. I also worry about setting up Jupyter on the lab server, since the network management in my lab is very strict and requires registration for most ports. I'd still like to know if there is a native Python workaround.

Comment: @MechanicPig Thanks for your suggestion! In fact, my task requires to read the large array through unordered indices. In this case, I think loading the entire array is better for performance?

Comment: Please at least try out jupyter console https://jupyter-console.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it may not be the answer to your question but it might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: @RichardSheridan Yes, thank you! The doc you linked seems like a good choice to start with in my case. I would definitely check it out later.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found [dynamic loading of Python code](https://medium.com/@david.bonn.2010/dynamic-loading-of-python-code-2617c04e5f3f) with `importlib` could serve as a simple workaround with native Python only.

The idea is to move the function under development (e.g., `some_task` in my toy example) to a separate script. The main script loads the large array for once, and then re-loads module from the other script to keep track of the code change. The toy example thus can be refactored like below:

In the main script:

```py
# main_script.py
import importlib.util
import sys


def load_module(source, module_name):
    """
    reads file source and loads it as a module

    :param source: file to load
    :param module_name: name of module to register in sys.modules
    :return: loaded module
    """

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, source)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    return module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pickle
    arr = pickle.load(open(FILE_PATH_TO_PICKLED_ARRAY, "rb"))
    
    while True:
        input("print Enter to re-load the module and run some_task")
        the_other_script = load_module(FILE_PATH_TO_THE_OTHER_SCRIPT, "the_other_script")
        the_other_script.some_task(arr)
```

In the other script:

```py
# the_other_script.py

def some_task(arr):
    # arr is read-only through the task
    # for example:
    result = arr.sum()
    return result
```

Finally, with `main_script.py` in running (and waiting for keyboard input), make any changes to `some_task` in `the_other_script.py` and press enter to signal the `main_script.py` to load and run the newest `some_task`.

`main_script.py` could further be improved to be more robust in case `some_task` throws exceptions or else.